# iOS Storyboard: how to reference like objects using an array index

Tags: ios, collections

[Xcode 10.1]
I'm developing an app using a storyboard and have 20+ sliders arranged in a line, similar to how the sliders on an equaliser would be arranged.  I would like to keep my code as clean as possible, so I'm wondering if there is a way whereby I only need to link one slider to my viewcontroller as an action/outlet and then access the full range as an array.  My sliders need to be connected as both an Outlet (to display the current setting on each read cycle, manually triggered) and an Action (to allow the user to adjust the value from what the last reading was).
Is this possible, and if so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IBOutlet collection for your slider and make the changes via a for loop
to apply changes to all the outlet first declare an collection of outlet like this in your view controller :-

```
@IBOutlet var sliders: [UISlider]!
```

Then link the slider one by one by attaching the outlet to the sliders array using the drag-drop method.

Here are some screenshots for better understanding:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you can access all the sliders like this :-

```
for slider in sliders{
    //do something with slider
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189938/discussion-between-dreambegin-and-gone).